# npm start giving error in nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, npm

//These are the error log details
  0 info it worked if it ends with ok 
    1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe', 
    1 verbose cli   'C:\Users\SamiUllahJan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js', 
    1 verbose cli   'start' ] 
    2 info using npm@5.4.2 
    3 info using node@v6.11.3 
    4 verbose stack Error: missing script: start
    4 verbose stack     at run (C:\Users\SamiUllahJan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:151:19) 
    4 verbose stack     at C:\Users\SamiUllahJan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:61:5
    4 verbose stack     at C:\Users\SamiUllahJan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:115:5 
    4 verbose stack     at C:\Users\SamiUllahJan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:402:5 
    4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (C:\Users\SamiUllahJan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:357:45)
    4 verbose stack     at final (C:\Users\SamiUllahJan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:400:3) 
    4 verbose stack     at then (C:\Users\SamiUllahJan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:160:5)
    4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext. (C:\Users\SamiUllahJan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:332:20) 
    4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Users\SamiUllahJan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16) 
    4 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:367:13) 
    5 verbose cwd C:\Samy\Code School 
    6 verbose Windows_NT 6.3.9600
    7 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\SamiUllahJan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start" 
    8 verbose node v6.11.3
    9 verbose npm  v5.4.2 
    10 error missing script: start
    11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Answer (score 0):

When you type in terminal

```
npm start
```

npm looks for the start script in package.json file, which you did not defined.

Change your package.json file to look like this (pay attention to scripts property):

```
{
  "name": "sample-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  }
}
```